# ElasticSearch suggestions on blog name, authors and tags

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I've been looking all over the place for a good answer to my question but I just can't find any...
I'm using ElasticSearch along with Laravel. I've used ElasticSearch on another project but never used suggestions. I'm following this tutorial as I think it provides a great starting point for using Laravel with ElasticSearch: https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/how-to-integrate-your-laravel-app-with-elasticsearch/

My question is about suggestions; I want my search to be a search-as-you-type just like the one you would find on Spotify. I want my users to type a few letters in the search box and have the results be organized into multiple categories: blogs, authors, tags.

If I index my data into one index, with authors and tags being blog's nested objects, I can easily get suggestions using the completion suggester for blog names, but not for nested objects. I could also split each model and index data separately into different indexes, but that would mean I would have to make 3 queries to get my results back.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I structure my data differently? Is making 3 queries the way to go or is there a way to have a single query output search results from different indexes?

Thanks!

Xavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that I did when I built a search-as-you-type was I used a separate index for suggestions. In your situation, you'd index the name (title, author, whatever) in one field and the type in another. Then you could search on one field and display the grouped results.

The advantage here is speed. This will likely be a heck of a lot faster than trying to do a suggester on your nested data. (Which you can probably do, but I'm not sure how.) And speed is pretty important for this type of feature.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense! I'm going to add a "link" field to your example and it should be perfect! Your answer is the kind of ideas that you don't find in the docs, and that's a shame.